# Unable to create new SSAS tabular models after SQL Server upgrade

Tags: ssas

We recently upgraded from SQL Server 2016 to 2022.  We are now unable to create tabular models.  The error message is below. Thank you!

Error message:

> An unexpected error occurred (file 'pcserialize.cpp', line 1535, function 'ASDatabase::Serialize').
>
> An unexpected error occurred (file 'pcserialize.cpp', line 1535, function 'ASDatabase::Serialize').
>
> An error occurred while opening the model. Click Details for more information.
>
> Call Stack:
>
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.AnalysisServicesClient.SendExecuteAndReadResponse(ImpactDetailCollection impacts, Boolean expectEmptyResults, Boolean throwIfError)
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.AnalysisServicesClient.Alter(IMajorObject obj, ObjectExpansion expansion, ImpactDetailCollection impact, Boolean allowCreate, XmlaWarningCollection warnings, JaXmlSerializer serializer)
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.Update(IMajorObject obj, UpdateOptions options, UpdateMode mode, XmlaWarningCollection warnings, ImpactDetailCollection impactResult)
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.SendUpdate(IMajorObject obj, UpdateOptions options, UpdateMode mode, XmlaWarningCollection warnings, ImpactDetailCollection impactResult)
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.MajorObject.Update(UpdateOptions options, UpdateMode mode, XmlaWarningCollection warnings)
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.BackEnd.DataModelingServer.CreateCatalog(String databaseName, Int32 localeID, DirectQueryMode directQueryMode, Int32 clientCompatibilityLevel)
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.BackEnd.DataModelingServer.CreateCatalog(String databaseName, Int32 localeID, DirectQueryMode directQueryMode, Int32 clientCompatibilityLevel)
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.VSHost.VSHostManager.OnNewProjectPrepareSandbox(Boolean isRealTimeMode, Int32 clientCompatibilityLevel)
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.VSHost.VSHostManager.PrepareSandbox(Boolean newProject, Boolean& isRefreshNeeded, Boolean& isImpersonationChanged, Boolean& saveRequired, List`1& truncatedTables, Boolean isRealTimeMode, Int32 clientCompatibilityLevel) at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.VSHost.VSHostManager.PrepareSandbox(Boolean newProject, Boolean& isRefreshNeeded, Boolean& isImpersonationChanged, Boolean& saveRequired, List`1& truncatedTables, Boolean isRealTimeMode, Int32 clientCompatibilityLevel)
> at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.VSHost.Integration.EditorFactory.CreateEditorInstance(UInt32 grfCreateDoc, String pszMkDocument, String pszPhysicalView, IVsHierarchy pvHier, UInt32 itemid, IntPtr punkDocDataExisting, IntPtr& ppunkDocView, IntPtr& ppunkDocData, String& pbstrEditorCaption, Guid& pguidCmdUI, Int32& pgrfCDW)

We sent the error to our platform group.  No luck so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I received this same error from Visual Studio 2022 after upgrading an Analysis Services project from SQL 2019 to SQL 2022. The first deployment to a development machine worked fine, but now I get the above error when trying to deploy to a production server. The same error is encountered from VS 2022 and from running an XMLA script reverse engineered from the development machine.

Comment: @SQLMonger  Thank you for your response.  We still have the same issue and are at the beginning stages of working with MS.

Comment: How is this error generated? By opening your project in visual studio? Can you create a brand new project OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit this issue on AWS and I finally resolved -

1. Locate msmdsrv.ini file (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
   Server\MSAS16.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Config)
2. Create a copy as a backup
3. Remove the line `<Gen2ServerKey>1</Gen2ServerKey>` and save
4. Restart SSAS Service

Googling "Gen2ServerKey" doesn't show anything so not sure what this does although I've not hit any issues since removing it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the help.  We ended up working with MS.  They told us to change <Gen2ServerKey>1</Gen2ServerKey> to: <Gen2ServerKey>0</Gen2ServerKey> in Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS16.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Config\msmdsrv.  We just made the change a few days ago and have also not had any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue, after upgrading from SQL 2016 to 2022.

Under the default virtual account for Analysis Services tabular, you cannot create a database.

Changing the account solved the problem.